# WebGL build will not take input in the Input Field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a scene built in Unity3D, and am trying to deploy it to WebGL. Within the scene I have an Input Field on the Canvas, which is supposed to take user input and search something within the scene.

However, when I load the WebGL build in the browser (I've tried on multiple browsers), clicking on the Input Field does not focus on it, so keyboard input isn't put into the Input Field. I have tried various methods using JavaScript to focus the game window, but no success.

Any idea how to get an Input Field to work on a WebGL scene?